# Meteor.loginwithpassword not working on iOS

Tags: javascript, ios, html, cordova, meteor

I'm working on a Meteor app for iOS 8.3 + and I'm having issues getting the accounts-password package to work on iOS.

I have this code for my login:

```
Template.login.events({
"submit #login-form": function()
{
    $.ajax({
        url: "http://www.drupalsite.com/api/v1/user/login.json",
        type: "POST",
        dataType: "json",
        data: $("#login-form").serializeArray(),
        error: function(data)
        {
            alert(data.responseJSON[0]);
        },
        success: function(Drupal)
        {
            alert("User being checked...");
            Accounts.createUser({
                username: $("#username").val(),
                password: $("#password").val(),
                email: Drupal.mail,
                profile: 
                    {
                        uid: Drupal.uid,
                        name: Drupal.user.field_first_name.und[0].safe_value + " "+ Drupal.user.field_last_name.und[0].safe_value
                    }

            }, function(error, result){

                if(error)
                {

                    Meteor.loginWithPassword($("#username").val(), $("#password").val());
                    alert("User Logged In");
                    $('.login').animate({
            }, 0, function() {
                $('.sign-in').removeClass('open');
                $('.login').removeClass('open');

            });

                } else
                {
                    alert("User Created");
                }

            });

        }
    });

    return false;
}
```

});

As you can see I'm validating a Drupal user, which works fine. The application itself works on the browser fine as well. The issue I get is that when I create the native ios app, the `Meteor.loginwithpassword` and `Accounts.createUser` methods stop working.

For testing purposes, I created a new meteor app that only  had the `{{> loginButtons}}` template in and deployed it to iOS. The sign in shows up in the simulator. It does not show up on the device.

Here's a full list of the packages I'm using:[image]

What am I doing wrong here?

**BTW, please let me know if there's anyway at all I can improve my question.**

Comment: Can you explain the significance of the Drupal login? It looks like you're posting login data to a third-party app/site and then also creating a user/logging in via Meteor...what is the expected result?

Comment: I have a Drupal site that has users already. I'm using the Drupal Services Module to grab their credentials. With their credentials I'm then creating a Meteor user, since only users of this specific Drupal install should have access to the app. This will make allow each user to have the same login info as they do on the website,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using the Accounts package in your mobile project you must have a server for your mobile device to call on.

While you can use the accounts package as is on your local machine (Be it Browser or Simulator) use this in the command line for your mobile device:

```
meteor build ~/.meteor/local --server=http://{{your server here}}.com
```

Afterwards do this:

```
meteor run ios-device --mobile-server http://{{your server here}}.com
```

To be sure your build is configured correctly.

If you don't have a server than deploy your app to the meteor.com servers as a temporary solution using:

```
meteor deploy "{{your-app-name-here}}.meteor.com"
```

Be careful here. A lot of meteor dev are testing so you want to try and make the name as unique as possible.

Hope this helps someone!

Comment: What's the purpose of doing `meteor build ~/.meteor/local --server=http://{{your server here}}.com` after you do `meteor run ios-device` ?

Comment: Sorry, I meant to say meteor build should happen before. I'll fix that now.

Comment: Thank you. But doesn't `run ios` still build it for you? What's the purpose of having a built copy at `~/.meteor/local`?

Answer (score 0):

To run it on your local machine (for development), first find your IP (`/sbin/ifconfig` will help on Linux and OSX).

Then just run

```
 meteor run  --mobile-server <IP:PORT> <PLATFORM-DEVICE>
```

In my case my development machine's IP is 192.168.1.66. And meteor runs on default port (3000) on it, so the command is:

```
 meteor run  --mobile-server 192.168.1.66:3000 ios-device
```

Notes:

- Without the port, it was not working for me.
- Make sure your phone/mobile-device is in the same network/has access to your development machine (ie: has access to 192.168.1.66 in my case)
- Running 'meteor build ...', was not necessary for me to make this work.