# Meteor createUser callback only works on web

Tags: meteor

```
Accounts.createUser({
  email: email,
  password: password
}, function (err) {
  console.log("inside createUser callback");
  if (err) {
    console.log("createUser failed", err);
    return false;
  }
  console.log("callback inside createUser");
  IonModal.close();
});
```

I am developing an ios app with Meteor (and Meteor Ionic), and I am stuck at a weird point. The callback for `createUser` only seems to be called when I test on  my browser. In my iOS device, everything works except the callback. I don't see any error message.

Does anyone have an idea or have had a similar problem?

Comment: Is it working from `mobile console`?

Comment: What's `mobile console`? Do you mean Chrome inspector tool's mobile view?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Meteor.loginwithpassword not working on iOS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30057502/meteor-loginwithpassword-not-working-on-ios)